# Why is there code showing in the following graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code for a plot:

```
DisPlot <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = EDDisWiderAllSexes, aes(x = stringr::str_wrap(Age.Group,15), y = `Population with a disability as a percentage`, fill = "Electoral Division"), width= 0.4, 
           position = position_nudge(0.22), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = StateDisWiderAllSexes, aes(x =  stringr::str_wrap(Age.Group,15), y = `Population with a disability as a percentage`, fill = "Ireland"), width= 0.4,
           position = position_nudge(-0.22), stat = "identity") +
  labs(fill = "Legend") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0))+
 coord_fixed(1/20) #+
```

however, this code displays "stringr::str_wrap(Age.Group,15)" below the category labels. I am unsure why this is the case and wondering if someone could help please?

Comment: do your `str_wrap` before sending to `ggplot()`, or use `labs(x = "another label")`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. The default labels for the `x` and `y` axis are whatever you passed to the `aes(x=, y=)` values. So you see the the exact code you put there. If you want to change the labels, use `labs(x="", y="")` to set them to whatever you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either control the x-label yourself in `scale_x_discrete(name="quux")` or `labs(x="quux")`, or call `str_wrap` before handing off to `ggplot`. (I'll `str_wrap(cyl)` from `mtcars`, which obviously doesn't do anything to the label itself, but it mimics the axis name change I suspect you're seeing.)

The problem:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(stringr::str_wrap(cyl), disp)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot with bad x-axis name]

Fixes, choose one from:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(stringr::str_wrap(cyl), disp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Quux")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(stringr::str_wrap(cyl), disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Quux")

mtcars |>
  transform(Quux = stringr::str_wrap(cyl)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Quux, disp)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot with fixed x-axis name]

I chose `"Quux"` as the name to display, there's no reason you can't use `="cyl"` for the original variable name. If you choose the third (`transform`) method, know that if anything else in your ggplot-code requires `cyl` unaltered, then you'll need to make a copy of it so that you have both the original and string-wrapped variant. Otherwise it should be perfectly fine to overwrite the original (at least in a copy-on-write pipeline).

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you r2evans. This worked perfectly